# How to open the sqlite database of an app without a tool break?

Tags: android, sqlite

I know how to get the database of an Android app (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577196/how-to-download-the-sqlite-database-of-an-android-app/59190011#59190011)). My current workflow is to load the database file to my pc via the adb.exe. Then I open the file with PhpStorms database tools. Is there a way to integrate the database functions to Android Studio without a need to leave the tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JetBrains' own [Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) which integrates into Android Studio.

Go to *Android Studio — Preferences — Plugins — Marketplace tab — search for Database Navigator* to install the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Is it possible to auto fetch the file?

Comment: @finder2 the approach described in [this article](https://medium.com/@mattyskala/browse-sqlite-database-in-android-studio-4fbba6cca105) may simplify things a bit (the part about getting the DB)